# powershell select-string output for loop foreach

Tags: bash, powershell, loops, foreach, select-string

I'm traditional bash user therefore i don't understand how to work foreach in powershell.

#### Powershell

I need output

```
Vasya
http://192.168.10.61:8085/data.json
Misha
http://192.168.10.82:8085/data.json
```

but I receive another output

```
Vasya
Misha
http://192.168.10.61:8085/data.json
http://192.168.10.82:8085/data.json
```

- Script

```perl
$pspath="E:\monitor.ps1"
$txtpath="E:\temp.txt"
$user1="Vasya"
$user2="Misha"
$ip1="http://192.168.10.61:8085/data.json"
$ip2="http://192.168.10.82:8085/data.json"


$list = @"
${user1}-${ip1}
${user2}-${ip2}
"@

foreach ($zab in $list)
{
    $regex_url = 'http://\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+:\d+/data.json'
    $regex_name = "([A-Z]|[a-z])\w+"
    $name =  echo $zab |%{$_.split('-')} |sls -pattern $regex_name -AllMatches |%{$_.Matches -notmatch 'http|json|data'} |%{$_.Value}
    $url = echo $zab |%{$_.split('-')} |sls -pattern $regex_url -AllMatches |%{$_.Matches} |%{$_.Value}
    echo $name
    echo $url
}
```

#### Bash

In bash work's perfect.

- Script

```perl
#!/bin/bash
users="Vasya-http://192.168.10.61:8085/data.json Misha-http://192.168.10.82:8085/data.json"


for zab in $users; do
    name=$(echo $zab |cut -f 1 -d -)
    url=$(echo $zab |cut -f 2 -d -)
    echo $name
    echo $url

done
exit 0
```

Help guys my hands are tied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
$list = @"
${user1}-${ip1}
${user2}-${ip2}
"@
```

is a single multi-line string, so the `foreach` loop is redundant.

Split the string before running `Select-String`:

```
foreach($zab in $list -split '\r?\n'){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PowerShell script is quite different from the bash script.

I don't know if you need the greater complexity with the `Select-String` for other reasons,
but in PowerShell it could also be as easy as:

```
$users="Vasya-http://192.168.10.61:8085/data.json Misha-http://192.168.10.82:8085/data.json"

foreach($zab in ($users -split ' ')){
    $name,$url = $zab -split '-',2
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $name
        Url  = $url
    }
}
```

for this sample object oriented output:

```
Name  Url
----  ---
Vasya http://192.168.10.61:8085/data.json
Misha http://192.168.10.82:8085/data.json
```